# Issues with fitting tables

Tags: tables, tabularx, threeparttable

I have this table code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,bm,siunitx}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}    

\begin{table}
        \caption{Variability of Asset Demands: Bond Model}
        \label{my-label}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            % \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}

                \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l*3{S[table-format=2.2]}}
                    \toprule
                    \multicolumn{4}{c}{${\gamma =5,\ \psi = 1,\ \rho =0.92^{1/4}  }$}\\
                    \midrule
                    &{${\Var(\alpha^m)/\Var(\alpha)}$}& {${\Var(\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$}  &{${\Cov(\alpha^m,\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$}\\
                    & {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} \\
                    \cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-4} 
                    Stock  & 81.27 & 22.18 & -1.73\\
                    Bond  &  76.53 & 4.10 &  9.69\\
                \end{tabular*}
                \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{5ex}}r*2{S[table-format=1.4]}*6{S[table-format=-1.4]}}
                    \midrule
                    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Percentage of Total Variation Explained By:}\\
                    \multicolumn{1}{l}{IG}   \\
                    &{$rtb_t$} & {$IG_t$ } & {$HY_t$} &{$EM_t$} & {$Conv_t$} & {$y_t$} & {$DefRate_t$} & {$spr_t$}  \\
                    $rtb_t$  &  26.69  &  0.87 &  1.69  & -0.12 &  2.98 &  -7.92  &-22.76  & 7.84\\
                    $IG_t$   &&5.77  &  3.59  & -0.22 &   2.97 &   1.16 &  -3.63 & 2.67\\
                    $HY_t$   &&&7.20 &  -0.25 &  7.07 & 1.17 &  -3.59  &  2.03\\
                    $EM_t$  &&&&0.01  & -0.2651  & -0.0295  &  0.1845  & -0.11\\
                    $Conv_t$  &&&&&12.28  &  0.7497 &  -2.6121   &-0.41\\
                    $y_t$  &&&&&&7.86 &  5.2971  &  0.77\\ 
                    $DefRate_t$&&&&&&&61.95&  -27.92\\
                    $spr_t$ &&&&&&&&35.74\\
                    \addlinespace
                    \multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}l}{HY}   \\
                    &{$rtb_t$} & {$IG_t$ } & {$HY_t$} &{$EM_t$} & {$Conv_t$} & {$y_t$} & {$DefRate_t$} & {$spr_t$}\\
                    $rtb_t$  &   14.70  &  0.16  &  1.40 & -4.91 &  -1.70  &  6.48 &  -1.80  & -5.57\\
                    $IG_t$   &&0.34  &  0.98  & -3.05  & -0.56  & -0.31 &  -0.09  & -0.62\\
                    $HY_t$   &&& 8.97 & -15.84 &  -6.09 & -1.45 &  -0.42  & -2.17\\
                    $EM_t$  &&&&49.71 & 11.25 &   1.79&  1.08  &  5.82\\
                    $Conv_t$  &&&&& 7.31  &  0.63  &  0.21 &  -0.30\\
                    $y_t$  &&&&&& 9.56  & -0.62 &   0.81\\ 
                    $DefRate_t$&&&&&&&0.71  &  2.86\\
                    $spr_t$ &&&&&&&&32.77\\
                    \addlinespace
                    \multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}l}{EM}   \\
                    &{$rtb_t$} & {$IG_t$ } & {$HY_t$} &{$EM_t$} & {$Conv_t$} & {$y_t$} & {$DefRate_t$} & {$spr_t$}\\
                    $rtb_t$  &  74.95 &   4.61  &  2.34 & -15.03  &  3.20 &  16.22 & -31.82   & 6.86\\
                    $IG_t$   && 56.52 &  9.27 & -52.73 &  5.96  & -4.47  & -9.49  &  4.37\\
                    $HY_t$   &&& 4.89 & -15.83  &  3.73 &  -1.18 &  -2.47 &  0.87\\
                    $EM_t$  &&&&91.09 &-12.65 &  2.68&  11.46& -4.30\\
                    $Conv_t$  &&&&& 5.04  & -0.58 & -1.39 &  -0.13\\
                    $y_t$  &&&&&& 11.74 & -5.40 &  -0.49\\ 
                    $DefRate_t$&&&&&&&43.12 & -12.17\\
                    $spr_t$ &&&&&&&&9.76\\
                    \addlinespace
                    \multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}l}{Conv}   \\
                    &{$rtb_t$} & {$IG_t$ } & {$HY_t$} &{$EM_t$} & {$Conv_t$} & {$y_t$} & {$DefRate_t$} & {$spr_t$}\\
                    $rtb_t$  &  24.30  & -1.81 &   1.68   & 0.37 &  -4.08& -12.49  &  7.80 & -12.37\\
                    $IG_t$   && 27.10  & -8.09  & -1.60  &  9.26 &  -4.18   &-2.83 &  9.58\\
                    $HY_t$   &&& 7.78   & 0.87  &-10.56  &  2.02   & 1.34 &  -3.49\\
                    $EM_t$  &&&&0.17 &  -1.24  &  0.15   & 0.21 &  -0.60\\
                    $Conv_t$  &&&&& 25.36 & -1.78 & -1.34  & -0.97\\
                    $y_t$  &&&&&&21.47 &  -3.14 & -2.11\\ 
                    $DefRate_t$&&&&&&&8.00& -16.60\\
                    $spr_t$ &&&&&&&&97.88\\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular*}
                % \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}
                    \item[] \textbf{Note:} Here can be the table notes
                \end{tablenotes}
            \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table}
```

The output of it is this one:

[image]

I do not understand how to extend the line above the variables in the matrix below the first panel. Do you know what I am doing wrong? 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive in the first `tabular*` environment. For the second `tabular*` enviroment, I'd say the main adjustment should consist of providing more precise formatting information for the eight columns of type `S`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,bm,siunitx}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}   
    \newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % "variable name" shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}  % make LaTeX figure out optimal intercol. space
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Variability of Asset Demands: Bond Model}
\label{my-label}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    l*3{S[table-format=2.2]}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{$\gamma =5$, $\psi = 1$, $\rho =0.92^{1/4}$  }\\
\midrule
& {${\Var(\alpha^m)/\Var(\alpha)}$}
& {${\Var(\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$}  
& {${\Cov(\alpha^m,\alpha^h)/\Var(\alpha)}$} \\
& {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
Stock  &  81.27 & 22.18 & -1.73\\
Bond   &  76.53 &  4.10 &  9.69\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\small
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   r    S[table-format= 2.2]
     *2{S[table-format= 1.2]}        
        S[table-format=-2.2]
     *3{S[table-format=-1.4]
        S[table-format= 2.2]}}
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{c}{Percentage of Total Variation Explained by}\\ 
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{IG}} 
& {$\vn{rtb}_t$}  & {$\vn{IG}_t$ } & {$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$}  & {$\vn{EM}_t$} 
& {$\vn{Conv}_t$} & {$y_t$}        & {$\vn{DefRate}_t$} & {$\vn{spr}_t$}  \\
$\vn{rtb}_t$  &  26.69  &  0.87 &  1.69  & -0.12 &  2.98 &  -7.92  &-22.76  & 7.84\\
$\vn{IG}_t$   &&5.77  &  3.59  & -0.22 &   2.97 &   1.16 &  -3.63 & 2.67\\
$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$   &&&7.20 &  -0.25 &  7.07 & 1.17 &  -3.59  &  2.03\\
$\vn{EM}_t$  &&&&0.01  & -0.2651  & -0.0295  &  0.1845  & -0.11\\
$\vn{Conv}_t$  &&&&&12.28  &  0.7497 &  -2.6121   &-0.41\\
$y_t$  &&&&&&7.86 &  5.2971  &  0.77\\ 
$\vn{DefRate}_t$&&&&&&&61.95&  -27.92\\
$\vn{spr}_t$ &&&&&&&&35.74\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{HY}}
& {$\vn{rtb}_t$}  & {$\vn{IG}_t$ } & {$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$}  & {$\vn{EM}_t$} 
& {$\vn{Conv}_t$} & {$y_t$}        & {$\vn{DefRate}_t$} & {$\vn{spr}_t$}  \\
$\vn{rtb}_t$  &   14.70  &  0.16  &  1.40 & -4.91 &  -1.70  &  6.48 &  -1.80  & -5.57\\
$\vn{IG}_t$   &&0.34  &  0.98  & -3.05  & -0.56  & -0.31 &  -0.09  & -0.62\\
$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$   &&& 8.97 & -15.84 &  -6.09 & -1.45 &  -0.42  & -2.17\\
$\vn{EM}_t$  &&&&49.71 & 11.25 &   1.79&  1.08  &  5.82\\
$\vn{Conv}_t$  &&&&& 7.31  &  0.63  &  0.21 &  -0.30\\
$y_t$  &&&&&& 9.56  & -0.62 &   0.81\\ 
$\vn{DefRate}_t$&&&&&&&0.71  &  2.86\\
$\vn{spr}_t$ &&&&&&&&32.77\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{EM}}  
& {$\vn{rtb}_t$}  & {$\vn{IG}_t$ } & {$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$}  & {$\vn{EM}_t$} 
& {$\vn{Conv}_t$} & {$y_t$}        & {$\vn{DefRate}_t$} & {$\vn{spr}_t$}  \\
$\vn{rtb}_t$  &  74.95 &   4.61  &  2.34 & -15.03  &  3.20 &  16.22 & -31.82   & 6.86\\
$\vn{IG}_t$   && 56.52 &  9.27 & -52.73 &  5.96  & -4.47  & -9.49  &  4.37\\
$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$   &&& 4.89 & -15.83  &  3.73 &  -1.18 &  -2.47 &  0.87\\
$\vn{EM}_t$  &&&&91.09 &-12.65 &  2.68&  11.46& -4.30\\
$\vn{Conv}_t$  &&&&& 5.04  & -0.58 & -1.39 &  -0.13\\
$y_t$  &&&&&& 11.74 & -5.40 &  -0.49\\ 
$\vn{DefRate}_t$&&&&&&&43.12 & -12.17\\
$\vn{spr}_t$ &&&&&&&&9.76\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Conv}}
& {$\vn{rtb}_t$}  & {$\vn{IG}_t$ } & {$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$}  & {$\vn{EM}_t$} 
& {$\vn{Conv}_t$} & {$y_t$}        & {$\vn{DefRate}_t$} & {$\vn{spr}_t$}  \\
$\vn{rtb}_t$  &  24.30  & -1.81 &   1.68   & 0.37 &  -4.08& -12.49  &  7.80 & -12.37\\
$\vn{IG}_t$   && 27.10  & -8.09  & -1.60  &  9.26 &  -4.18   &-2.83 &  9.58\\
$\vn{HY}_{\!t}$   &&& 7.78   & 0.87  &-10.56  &  2.02   & 1.34 &  -3.49\\
$\vn{EM}_t$  &&&&0.17 &  -1.24  &  0.15   & 0.21 &  -0.60\\
$\vn{Conv}_t$  &&&&& 25.36 & -1.78 & -1.34  & -0.97\\
$y_t$  &&&&&&21.47 &  -3.14 & -2.11\\ 
$\vn{DefRate}_t$&&&&&&&8.00& -16.60\\
$\vn{spr}_t$ &&&&&&&&97.88\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[]\textbf{Note:} Here can be the table notes
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that is what I was looking for!